# How to use different name for podspec

Tags: flutter

I am familiar with writing the Flutter plugin. I have developed a basic Flutter plugin to invoke native functions.

It seems that Flutter mandates the podspec file name to match the plugin's name. For instance, if my project name is "zoo," the .podspec file within the `ios/` folder must also be named "zoo.podspec."

This results in a circular dependency issue for us as zoo.podspec is loading a native iOS framework of the same name.

The only solution I found is to change the name of the project but I like to keep it as the last-resort solution. Is there a way to modify the podspec file name to resolve this issue?